# Cross-browser compatible CSS liquid layout with 3 columns of 100% width/height

Tags: css, layout, html

I started to create my HTML/CSS layout based on [this](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm) article and was more/less successful. However, I think that I messed up somewhere with my css, since this page is not displayed in the same way in IE or Chrome/Firefox...

Basically, my idea is to have 3 equal-width columns, with 100% height. Content of each column should have some padding on left, top and right sides, and 'main' links should be positioned in the bottom of each column, aligned in center of its column.

This is the sketch of my layout

[image]

You can see my current result [here](http://www.krlja-ustvari.hr/test). If you look this page in Chrome/Firefox you can see that content `divs` are 'bleeding' out of my page, however, in IE content `divs` fit nicely (I put border on content `divs` for testing purposes only). I don't believe that IE is rendering my CSS correctly, rather I believe that I'm doing something wrong with my CSS, but really not sure what. Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: fiddle is here [http://jsfiddle.net/kJL5m/](http://jsfiddle.net/kJL5m/), however it won't resize to 100% height at all here :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting height of 100% but also setting padding/margins etc, the height is the inner height and padding/margins/borders will be added to this, thus causing an overflow.

EDIT: Either set padding/margins/borders as percentages so that they + height add up to 100% or calculate pixels appropriatley using javascript to tell you the window height in pixels allowing you to determine the correct height for each column.  You can always fire this on resize of the window to act like a 100% rule in css.

Comment: Ah, I see... I should remove `padding-top: 20px;` from my divs. If I do that, seems like it helped a bit... Will try to play around with those percentages.

Comment: Padding, Margins and Borders will all add to the overall displayed height, if your css height is already 100% then the height will actually become `100% + padding-top + padding-bottom + margin-top + margin-bottom + border-bottom-width + border-top-width`